# Height setter ignored on custom Window

Tags: wpf, xaml

I added a Custom Control to my project and changed the parent type to Window. I show it on a button click.

I have style setters for height and width, but only the one defined first in the xaml has effect. The other shows larger than styled.

Anyone know what's happening here?

[image]

In generic.xaml:

```
<Style TargetType="{x:Type local:ChildWindow}">
    <Setter Property="Width" Value="300"/>
    <Setter Property="Height" Value="300"/>
    <Setter Property="Template">
        <Setter.Value>
            <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type local:ChildWindow}">
                <TextBlock Background="White">Child window</TextBlock>
            </ControlTemplate>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
</Style>
```

ChildWindow.cs is default except the parent is now "Window":

```cs
public class ChildWindow : Window
{
    static ChildWindow()
    {
        DefaultStyleKeyProperty.OverrideMetadata(typeof(ChildWindow), new FrameworkPropertyMetadata(typeof(ChildWindow)));
    }
}
```

MainWindow.xaml.cs shows the ChildWindow:

```cs
private void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    var childWindow = new ChildWindow();
    childWindow.Show();
}
```

Comment: You're probably setting `Height` explicitly in the XAML, or doing sometihng else in the XAML that breaks it. XAML element attributes override Style setters.

Comment: Good thought, but the code above is all I've added/changed from the default project template (WpfApp1). The only XAML related to ChildWindow is shown.

Comment: Well butter me and call me a biscuit, you're absolutely right.

Comment: If you figure this one out, it's a deal. :)

Comment: I can give you a choice of workarounds, but I'm absolutely baffled why the second setter is failing. No joy on Google.

Comment: Ya, same boat. Must be a Window implementation quirk. I posted my workaround, but post yours if it might be better. Thanks for looking into it!

Comment: Your workaround eats mine for breakfast. I never knew about `OverrideMetadata`. Thanks! Probably for the best if we call off the butter thing anyhow.

Answer (score 1):

**Workaround:**
I haven't found why it behaves like that, or how to make the style setters work, but a workaround is to get rid of the style setters and set the default values for the Width and Height dependency properties. I did this in the static constructor:

```cs
static ChildWindow()
{
    DefaultStyleKeyProperty.OverrideMetadata(typeof(ChildWindow), new FrameworkPropertyMetadata(typeof(ChildWindow)));

    // Get rid of the style setters and add this:
    WidthProperty.OverrideMetadata(typeof(ChildWindow), new FrameworkPropertyMetadata(300.0));
    HeightProperty.OverrideMetadata(typeof(ChildWindow), new FrameworkPropertyMetadata(300.0));
}
```